# Image gives NULL when passing from service to controller using MultipartFile in spring

Tags: angular, spring, scala

I have an image passing from the angular to the RestController. But when it's reached the controller, it gives me null. I have tried to use Multipart as the data type, it gives null also. Then, I changed to string data type and get the bytes. While I want to save it, the ImageIO cannot process due to the image is null. I have checked the console and the file exists, but it gives null at the controller.

[controller.scala]

```
uploadFile(file: any):Observable<number> {
const formData: FormData = new FormData();
for (const file of files) {
   formData.append('imageList', files)
}

return this.http.post('${TeaService.URL}/rest/tea/upload-menu', formData, {}).map(res => res.json());
}
```

[service.ts]

```
@RequestMapping(value = Array("upload-menu"))
def uploadMenu(imageList: MultipartFile): Long= {
if(imageList != null)
    println("image list got value")
else 
    println("image list is null")
100    
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved it by adding the below line in properties file

```
spring.http.multipart.enabled=true
```